# How to union 2 objects (with same data structure) and render in Rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, render

In our Rails 3.2.12 app, there is situation in which two variables (stored a subset of a table with the same data structure) returned and need to be combine to be rendered in index view. Let's take @project1 and @project2 for example. Both @project1 and @project2 have a subset of data retrieved from `project` table. Before rendering, a few things needs to be done:

```
1. merge @project1 and @project2 into @project
2. get rid of duplicate record in @project. like @project.uniq
3. render @project as json
```

For merge, we probably can do `@project = @project1.to_json + @project2.to_json`. Then `@project` is a `json` object.

How to get rid of identical records in `@project`? We don't know how to do.

For rendering @project, can we do `render :json => @project in controller index (response_to do |format| format.json { render :json => @project })`?. Can we use the same `index.html.erb` to `render` json `@project` without any change (we have a `helper method` applied to `each of @project`  in index view)?

Can someone comment on the steps above (working or not) and shed light on how to get rid of duplicate records in a json object?

Also is there any solution like `@project = @project1 + @project2` existing? That's may be a wild imagination.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of identical records in @project?"

Comment: For example, if project id 1 is in both /@project1 and /@project2, only one copy of project id1 needs to present and another identical copy needs to be removed in @project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the record objects into hashes and then merge the hashes.

```
h1 = @project1.attributes;
h2 = @project2.attributes;
@project.attributes = h1.merge(h2);
```

Added: correct answer was found after some exchange in comments below.

```
@project = @project1.merge(@project2).uniq
```

Comment: h1.merge(h2) == h2 return true. Only one hash left. Not working.

Comment: h1.merge(h2) returns a hash that has all the keys in h2 and their value, plus any keys in h1 that are not in h2 and their values. If you are finding h1.merge(h2) == h2, then h1 had no keys not found in h2. If you want different behavior, please explain what behavior you want.

Comment: Is uniqueness determined only by the record id? In other words, if record p1 has id 50, record p2 has id 55, and record p3 has id 50 (and so is a duplicate of p1), and records p2 and p1 are identical except for the id field, should the union be only record p1, or should it be p1 and p2?

Comment: yes, uniq record id means they are not the same. The records stored in variables are pulling from the same table and share the exact same structure.

Comment: In case above, only record 50 & 55 need to be present in final result. both 50 in p1 and p3 are duplicate and only one is needed.